# Dropdown list with population with where clause

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to populate the second dropdown list `GetCity()` with values from a Data Base that are dependent on whatever was selected in the the first list or `GetCounty()` dropdown. Where would i add the where clause?

```
public class NewsModel : BaseModel
{
    [Required]
    public int? FKCountyId { get; set; }
    public string County { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int? FKCityId { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }


    public List<SelectListItem> GetCounty()
    {
        List<SelectListItem> lst = new List<SelectListItem>();
        lst.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "Please select County", Value = "" });
        foreach (var item in LambertonContext.NewsCounties)
        {
            lst.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = item.County, Value = item.PKCountyId.ToString() });
        }
        return lst;
    }

    public List<SelectListItem> GetCity()
    {
        List<SelectListItem> lst = new List<SelectListItem>();
        lst.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "Please select City", Value = "" });
        foreach (var item in LambertonContext.NewsCities)
        {
            lst.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = item.City, Value = item.PKCityId.ToString() });
        }
        return lst;
        }
}


 <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.FKCountyId, new { @class = "col-sm-2 col-sm-2 control-label" })
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.FKCountyId, Model.GetCounty())
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.FKCityId, new { @class = "col-sm-2 col-sm-2 control-label" })
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.FKCityId, Model.GetCity())
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to pass the `CountyId` to your `GetCity()` and filter your list;
try this:

```
 public List<SelectListItem> GetCity(string CountyId)
    {
        List<SelectListItem> lst = new List<SelectListItem>();
        lst.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "Please select City", Value = "" });
        foreach (var item in LambertonContext.NewsCities.Where(FKCountyId == GetCounty().Value))
        {
            lst.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = item.City, Value = item.PKCityId.ToString() });
        }
        return lst;
        }
```

Comment: Alundra, do i have to postback the GetCounty dropdown to get the value that is selected in the dropdown?

Comment: you dont need to post-back , you already have the FK relationship.
You will need an AJAX call to perform populate the city dropdown linst

Comment: OK but LambertonContext.NewsCities.Where(FKCountyId == GetCounty().Value) is giving me Error 157 'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem>' does not contain a definition for 'Value' and no extension method 'Value' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: OK an ajax call that is triggered by the first dropdown and sends the value selected in the firstdropdown to code that populates the seconddropdown.

Comment: The view code is at the bottom. i dont have the ajax call

Comment: You need extra work on the the view code, You will need some JS script code to make it work. It's beyond the scope of your initial question

Comment: please take a look at new question.    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29612193/trying-to-populate-a-sub-list-on-changing-the-main-list-using-jquery-ajax

Comment: I just posted an answer to your other question. the answer i provided here is correct for the question you posted , please consider voting up again and mark it as an answer